# Flutter BottomNavigationBar changes only screens but doesn't selection

Tags: flutter

Hi I'm new to Flutter and I'm trying to add BottomNavigationBar to my application, but I got a problem as I wrote in title.

As you can see below, I'm placing a state of currentIndex and a method called when tapped in a different class.

page_frame.dart (This has a state and a method)

```
// ...

class PageFrame extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageFrame({super.key});

  @override
  State<PageFrame> createState() => _PageFrameState();
}

class _PageFrameState extends State<PageFrame> {
  int _currentPageIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> _pages = <Widget>[
    const Home(),
    const Announcement()
  ];

  void _onPageTap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentPageIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor     : const Color(0xFF183977),
      body                : _pages.elementAt(_currentPageIndex),
      bottomNavigationBar : SPBottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex : _currentPageIndex,
        onTap        : _onPageTap
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my_bottom_navigation_var.dart (This receives a state and a method from above)

```
// ...

class MyBottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final int currentIndex;
  final ValueChanged<int> onTap;
  const MyBottomNavigationBar({required this.currentIndex, required this.onTap, Key? key})
    : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyBottomNavigationBar> createState() => _MyBottomNavigationBarState();
}

class _MyBottomNavigationBarState extends State<MyBottomNavigationBar> {
  late int currentIndex;
  late ValueChanged<int> onTap;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentIndex = widget.currentIndex;
    onTap        = widget.onTap;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      unselectedItemColor : const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      selectedItemColor   : const Color(0xFF008BF1),
      showUnselectedLabels: true,
      items               : const [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon            : Icon(Icons.home),
          label           : 'Home',
          backgroundColor : Color(0xFF000000)
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon            : Icon(Icons.announcement),
          label           : 'Announcement',
          backgroundColor : Color(0xFF000000)
        )
      ],
      currentIndex : currentIndex,
      onTap        : onTap,
    );
  }
}
```

This results in if I tap an icon of Announcement, only the screen changes from Home to Announcement, but what icon of selected is still Home like this:
[Screen : Home, Selection : Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIk7D.png)
[Screen : Announcement, Selection : Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aVYQ.png)
I thought this could happens because of lack of interactivity, even if it were, I have no idea how to get this interactive. Please tell me what to do.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MyBottomNavigationBar` state class has its life-cycle, It gets `currentIndex` value for the 1st time on `initState`. You can directly access the widget class variable with

```
widget.variableName
```

You can use like

```dart
class MyBottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final int currentIndex;
  final ValueChanged<int> onTap;
  const MyBottomNavigationBar(
      {required this.currentIndex, required this.onTap, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyBottomNavigationBar> createState() => _MyBottomNavigationBarState();
}

class _MyBottomNavigationBarState extends State<MyBottomNavigationBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      unselectedItemColor: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      selectedItemColor: const Color(0xFF008BF1),
      showUnselectedLabels: true,
      items: const [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF000000)),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.announcement),
            label: 'Announcement',
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF000000))
      ],
      currentIndex: widget.currentIndex,
      onTap: widget.onTap,
    );
  }
}
```

Also you can just use stateless widget here, the parent(home)  widget pass new value on index changes and this widget get rebuild automatically.

```dart
class MyBottomNavigationBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final int currentIndex;
  final ValueChanged<int> onTap;
  const MyBottomNavigationBar(
      {required this.currentIndex, required this.onTap, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      unselectedItemColor: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      selectedItemColor: const Color(0xFF008BF1),
      showUnselectedLabels: true,
      items: const [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF000000)),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.announcement),
            label: 'Announcement',
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF000000))
      ],
      currentIndex: currentIndex,
      onTap: onTap,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your main screen is updating while the `NavigationBar` is not is simply because they have two *different* states.

In your main screen, you have a variable with the current page index and when the user taps the `NavigationBar` you update this and redraw the widget. This will *not* redraw the child widget, which has its own state that hasn't changed.

There are two simple fixes for this.

### NavigationBar as StatelessWidget

Since the Navbar never uses its state, you could convert it into a `StatelessWidget` and pass the active index in the constructor. That way, when the main screen changes it will rebuild the `NavigationBar` with the new index.

```
class MyBottomNavigationBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final int currentIndex;
  final ValueChanged<int> onTap;
  const MyBottomNavigationBar(
      {Key? key, required this.currentIndex, required this.onTap})
      : super(key: key);
  // ...
```

### NavigationBar as StatefulWidget

The other way to fix this is to keep the `NavigationBar` as a `StatefulWidget` but when the user taps you update the state in here and also pass up the selected index. Just change the `onTap()` as follows:

Instead of `onTap: onTap` you will write

```
onTap: (index) {
  setState((){
    currentIndex = index;
  });
  widget.onTap(index);
}
```

As you can see, you don't even need to create a state variable for the callback function inside the `initState()`. Just call it here.

Comment: Sorry for late reply and thank you for your answer! Though I'm afraid but I'll choose another one, this also helps me to understand. I really appreciate you.